# gradle copy files to directory with wildcard

Tags: tomcat, gradle, copy, wildcard

Gradle: copy a war to an existing tomcat

```
/path/tomcat-[version]/webapps
```

The version can be any version, and I do not want to hardcode it. Only one tomcat under the /path.

```
task copyWar(type: Copy) {
   from warPath
   destinationDir "/path/tomcat-*/webapps"

}
```

The tomcat directory does not exist during evaluation.

### UPDATE

Tried:

```
task copyWar(type: Copy) {
   from warPath

   doFirst {
        // find tomcat directory name, set tomcatName
        destinationDir file("/path/$tomcatName/webapps")
   }

}
```

Gradle complains the destinationDir is not set. Obviously it is too late to set it in doFirst {} for up-to-date check.

Answer (score 2):

As Gradle scripts are, basically, Groovy ones, you can do it like this:

```
task copyWar(type:Copy) {
    from warPath
    def tomcatDir = new File("/path").listFiles().find {it.name.startsWith("tomcat-")}
    into new File(tomcatDir, "webapps")
}
```

Please note, that this snippet will be executed in configuration phase and it includes the filesystem access, so potentially, configuration phase may have a performance penalty

Comment: But the tomcat-* directory is created by another task (installTomcat), so it does not exist during configuration.

Comment: Then you can simply read the directory name from the `installTomcat` task. Where does this task comes from?

Comment: The task calls a Exec command to install tomcat. The tomcat version is unknown until it is installed.